# Find the First occurrence value of data in Query

Tags: ms-access, ms-query

I have a table that has a lot of data, but only of four categories. I would like to return the ID of the First occurrence and last occurrence, of the type. The following is the simplified version of my data..

```
ID    |    FName    |    Password   |    Category    |    Outcome
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1     |    Dan      |    something  |    NEW         |    8
2     |    Faye     |    another    |    NEW         |    1
:
:
189   |    Chris    |    Password   |    OLD         |    2
190   |    Matt     |    Milk       |    OLD         |    7
:
:
1169  |    Mark     |    Dog        |    LITE        |    3
1170  |    Nick     |    Land       |    LITE        |    1
```

So I would like to have a query that will return the result as

```
CATEGORY    |    ID_START   |    ID_END
----------------------------------------
NEW         |    1          |    188     
OLD         |    189        |    1168     
LITE        |    1169       |    9999
```

I am using Access 2010. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: If Barranka's answer isn't exactly what you needed, it may help to explain why those FName, Password, and Outcome columns are relevant to your question.

Comment: Thanks HansUp the other fields are in the table I only would like to display the ID start and End.. @Barranka's solution worked good thanks for your reply..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can sugest this:

```
select category, min(id) as idStart, max(id) as idEnd
from tbl
group by category
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: That works perfect @Barranka.. I did that to start with, but for some reason it did not return what I wanted.. I tried as you showed me, it works.. strange.. but works.. Thanks. :)